# Find the intersections of $C(0,1)$ and $C(1,\sqrt{2})$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Find the intersections of $C(0,1)$ and $C(1,\sqrt{2})$.

I am making a test and in the solutions it says that the intersecting points are $i$ and $-i$. The only problem here is that when i try solving the equation:

$e^{ix} = \sqrt{2}e^{ix} + 1$

I don't seem to get the right solution where x should be $\frac{\pi}{2}$. I filled in the equation in wolfram alpha but that was wrong as well.

Is there something i am doing wrong here?

Kees

Comment: Draw a picture. The answer will be fairly obvious. Are you looking for the intersections of the boundaries or the sets themselves?

Comment: What is B(x,y)?

Comment: $B(x,y) = \{z:|z-x|<y\}$

Comment: @copper.hat i mean the inetersections of the boundries, so actually $C(0,1)$ and $C(1,\sqrt{2})$

Comment: @KeesTil - I'm voting to keep this open for now, but you should really put some effort into explaining yourself if you don't want the question closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to solve $|z|=1, |z-1|=\sqrt{2}$.

Then squaring gives $z \bar{z} = 1, z \bar{z} -2 \operatorname{re} z + 1 = 2$.

Solving these shows that $\operatorname{re} z=0$, so look for solutions
of the form $\alpha i$, where $\alpha $ is real. This gives $\alpha = \pm 1$.

Comment: why does my tactic not work? I wrote the equation in polar coordinates and the left side represent the unitary circle and the right side represents $C(1,\sqrt{2})$

Comment: You can't expect the same $x$ to work on the left and right hand sides in general. You should solve $e^{ix} = 1+\sqrt{2}e^{iy}$.

Comment: thanks i see it know that was pretty dumb xD

Comment: Everyone makes mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the real number $x$ doesn't mean the same thing on both sides of your equation

try solving

$e^{i \theta_1} = \sqrt{2} e^{i \theta_2} + 1$

split into 2 real equations and two real unknowns.